# What, if anything, is needed besides 'git fsck' to verify the integrity of a repository?

Tags: git

What would I need to do, in addition to using `git fsck`, to verify that the version controlled content of an archived .git repo is unchanged?

Background: I'm considering directly archiving a Git repo (the .git directory) onto e.g. an external SSD. Later I want to be able to verify that none of the content of the archived .git directory has changed, e.g. due to a random bit flip or corruption of the storage media. (I don't care about threats related to someone intentionally changing the archive).

I know I could e.g. create a tar file that contains the .git directory and use md5sum to verify that the tar file is unchanged.

However, I'm wondering if 'git fsck' is a partial solution that's already doing most of the needed work. Maybe it's the case that in addition to 'git fsck', I just need to e.g. use md5sum to verify that some of the plain-text files inside the .git directory are unchanged.

Note: I'm not familiar with how `git fsck` works or what it does. So if using it is a silly idea, just let me know. It just seems like it'd be nice to not have to embed the .git directory inside a tar file.